# Using Relative URLs in Templates

Tags: python, django

I am working with book *"Tango with Django*".Have problem with using relative **URL**s.

---

To be shortly
 this:`<a href="{% url 'rango:add_page' rango:category.slug %}">Add a Page</a>` results to this : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/category//add_page/`

---

Function in *rango/views.py*:

```
def show_category(request,category_name_slug):
context_dict= {}

try:
    category=Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
    pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)
    context_dict['pages']=pages
    context_dict['category']=category
except Category.DoesNotExist:
    context_dict['category']= None
    context_dict['pages'] = None
return render(request,'rango/category.html',context_dict)
```

---

```
def add_page(request,category_name_slug):
try:
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)
except Category.DoesNotExist:
    category = None


form=PageForm()

if request.method=='POST':
    form = PageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        if category:
            page = form.save(commit=False)
            page.category = category
            page.views = 0
            page.save()
        return show_category(request, category_name_slug)

    else:
        print(form.errors)
context_dict = {'form': form, 'category': category}
return render(request,'rango/add_page.html',context_dict)
```

**rango/urls.py** :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from rango import views
app_name = 'rango'

urlpatterns =[
url(r'^$',views.index ,name='index'),
url(r'^about/$',views.about , name = 'about'),
url(r'^add_category/$',views.add_category,name='add_category'),
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/?$',views.show_category,name='show_category'),
url(r'^category/(?P<category_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/add_page/?$', views.add_page, name='add_page'),
]
```

Tried to use **rango** **namespace** like : `'rango:add_page'` ,
and

```
<a href="/rango/category/{{ category_name_slug }}/add_page/">Add a Page</a>
```

, and

```
<a href="/rango/category/{{ category.slug }}/add_page/">Add a Page</a>
```

,but it didnt helped me.

Comment: You probably have an extra `/` in your `urls.py` file. If you copy all of your urlconf, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: What is the view that is rendering the page with the link? The code you have shown is for the view the link is going to.

Comment: @makaveli Added

Comment: @Daniel Roseman added

Comment: It seems that you don't have the `category_name_slug` variable defined on initial rendering so try printing that variable out (and also see if the object you're trying to get is defined after getting) and see why the variable isn't evaluated.

Comment: try   {% url 'rango:add_page' category.slug %} 
for me rango:category.slug evaluate to ""
so   http://127.0.0.1:8000/rango/category/<empty string>/add_page/

Comment: TY.Tried your tag.It helps me with some changes.